# req.body.title and req.body.content are undefined in Express

Tags: node.js, mongoose, post, postman

Title: req.body.title and req.body.content are undefined in Express
Description
I am trying to access the title and content of a document using app.post(), but the values are coming back as undefined. I have installed the body-parser middleware and configured it, and I am sending a POST request with the correct Content-Type header. The request body is in JSON format, and it is not empty.

Code

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/documents', (req, res) => {
const title = req.body.title;
const content = req.body.content;

console.log(title, content);

res.send('Document created successfully.');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('App listening on port 3000.');
});
```

Troubleshooting
I have tried the following things to troubleshoot the problem, but I have not been able to resolve it:

I have checked the syntax of my code.
I have checked the format of the request body.
I have checked the Content-Type header.
Questions
I am not sure what else to try. Can anyone help me figure out why req.body.title and req.body.content are coming back as undefined?

Comment: How do you send request? If you use postman, can you add screenshot?

Comment: Can you add to the question an exemple of the `request.body` you receive? (don't forget to obfuscate any personal data, what we need is the variable type / structure)

Comment: It worked . I just  needed to configure postman a bit

Answer (score 0):

I saw from your tags that you are using postman.

[image]

Where did I put those ugly darts. You should solve like this. If it works, investigate well to understand what has been done.